# K8 create pod with uppercase image name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, docker-image

How to create a Kubernetes pod object with the image name contains upper cases and hyphen in it. Is this possible?

I tried different way by setting it in env variable but nothing works?

Comment: Did you read this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-names

Comment: Yep That specifies image tags contains upper case. My query is wat if image name contain upper case and hyphen.

Comment: Add the sample YAML file too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.  Yep, this question was asked in K8 CKAD exam.
I found there is a way, let me update,

the question is to create a K8 pod object with the image name which has an upper case. To do that,

1. Create a regular pod using 'kubectl run nginx --image=nginx'
2. Now re-set the image name using 'kubectl set image pod/nginx nginx=Nginx'

Using this way you can set the image name which has an upper case in it.
Yes, I know that the dockerName should not be in upper case. But I suspect the intention behind this question is to identify are there any way to create a pod with an uppercase image name.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use UPPER CASE as docker image name, hence  you cant use it in kubernetes.

[docker tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#extended-description) says:

> An image **name** is made up of slash-separated name components,
> optionally prefixed by a registry hostname. The hostname must comply
> with standard DNS rules, but may not contain underscores. If a
> hostname is present, it may optionally be followed by a port number in
> the format :8080. If not present, the command uses Docker’s public
> registry located at registry-1.docker.io by default. **Name components
> may contain lowercase letters, digits and separators. A separator is
> defined as a period, one or two underscores, or one or more dashes. A
> name component may not start or end with a separator.**
>
> A tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain lowercase and uppercase
> letters, digits, underscores, periods and dashes. A tag name may not
> start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128
> characters.

**Name components may contain lowercase letters, digits and separators.**  You dont have Upper case letters in this list.

You will receive `Error parsing reference: "blabla/Hello-world:latest" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase`